# What is the correct way to save a Vaadin CheckBox to JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin-flow

I'm looking to find a Vaadin example but I didn't find any using of Checkbox to JPA at all.

I try this but is work only if I click one time on a checkbox, **if click again on the same box** is breaks off

```
private Grid createGrid() {
    grid = new Grid<>();
    ListDataProvider<User> dataProvider = DataProvider.ofCollection(userRepository.findAll());
    grid.setDataProvider(dataProvider);
    grid.setHeight("100%");
    grid.setMaxWidth("840px");

    grid.addColumn(new ComponentRenderer<>(this::createUserInfo)).setWidth(UIUtils.COLUMN_WIDTH_XL);
    grid.addComponentColumn(u -> {
        Checkbox c = new Checkbox();
        c.getStyle().set("font-size", "24px");
        c.setValue(u.isAnwesend());
        c.addValueChangeListener(click -> {
            changeIsAnwesend(u);
        });

        return c;
    })
            .setFlexGrow(0)
            .setWidth(UIUtils.COLUMN_WIDTH_XS);

    grid.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_NO_ROW_BORDERS);

    return grid;
}

private void changeIsAnwesend(User user) {
    user.setAnwesend(!user.isAnwesend());
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

This are the errors:

```
org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [com.softwareaustria.backend.data.entity.User] with identifier [21]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.softwareaustria.backend.data.entity.User#21]

Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.softwareaustria.backend.data.entity.User#21] *
```

**Before I begin to investigate in Hibernate I ask what is the correct and usual way to save Checkbox to JPA in Vaadin.**

Thanks a lot!

**RESOLVED:**

**Thanks sugestion from @Kaspar Scherrer and @Simon Martinelli**

I change method parameters to (User user, Grid grid)
and add after *userRepository.save(user);*

```
  grid.setItems(userRepository.findAll());
```

and finally work!

**This is the working code:**

```
private Grid createGrid() {
        grid = new Grid<>();
        ListDataProvider<User> dataProvider = DataProvider.ofCollection(userRepository.findAll());
        grid.setDataProvider(dataProvider);
        grid.setHeight("100%");
        grid.setMaxWidth("840px");

        grid.addColumn(new ComponentRenderer<>(this::createUserInfo)).setWidth(UIUtils.COLUMN_WIDTH_XL);
        grid.addComponentColumn(u -> {
            Checkbox checkbox = new Checkbox();
            checkbox.getStyle().set("font-size", "24px");
            checkbox.setValue(u.isAnwesend());
            checkbox.addValueChangeListener(click -> {
                changeIsAnwesend(u, grid);
            });

            return checkbox;
        })
                .setFlexGrow(0)
                .setWidth(UIUtils.COLUMN_WIDTH_XS);

        grid.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_NO_ROW_BORDERS);

        return grid;
    }

       private void changeIsAnwesend(User user, Grid grid) {
    user.setAnwesend(!user.isAnwesend());
    userRepository.save(user);
    refresh();
}

private void refresh() {
    grid.setItems(userRepository.findAll());
}
```

Comment: IMHO this is the wrong way around.  Your mentioned problem most likely hits you only the second time you toggled the bool on the user?  So now you fixed your save on the stale entity for the next time, if the unterlying entity will not be changed by a different user. I think you should reload the user in the beginning of `changeIsAnwesend` and make sure the "toggle" is the user intention (not just negating the value from the grid last seen). Then reload the grid etc. like you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Simon Martinelli's answer. Your data is "stale" (not up to date) and needs to be reloaded.
Here is how you could do it.

```
checkbox.addValueChangeListener(click -> {
    changeIsAnwesend(u, grid);
});

....

private void changeIsAnwesend(User user, Grid grid) {
    user.setAnwesend(!user.isAnwesend());
    //grid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.SINGLE).select(user);
    userRepository.save(user);

    // reload data from DB
    ListDataProvider<User> dataProvider = DataProvider.ofCollection(userRepository.findAll());
    grid.setDataProvider(dataProvider);

    // or in short form (it will do the same):
    // grid.setItems(userRepository.findAll());
}
```

Comment: Finally I found the sucker:

grid.setItems(userRepository.findAll());

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion!

Comment: Ok so `grid.setItems(userRepository.findAll());` is the short form of my second approach. Does that mean the first approach did not work? If so I will edit it out of my answer.

Comment: yes, for some reasons (to ex. I use Vaadin 14) is work only with grid.setItems(userRepository.findAll()); I improved to a elegant   refresh(); method: private void refresh() { grid.setItems(userRepository.findAll()); }

Answer (score 1):

Your way seams to be viable but you have another problem.

You get a `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` that means in the meanwhile your User object was already changed in the database.

You have to reload the entity from the database before setting the anwesend flag.

Comment: I'm happy to help